# c++ destructor crash program

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I made a program that substract two arrays from 2 objects of the same class and then put them in a new array and display them. The program work until the end when he crashes. I think it's the destructor because if i remove him the program exit normally I don't know why I think I allocated correctly memory still...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class math{
private: 
    float *tab;
    float *result;
    int size;
public:
    math(int n);
    void subtract(math,int);
    void afis(){
        cout<<"Result of subtraction: ";
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            cout<<result[i]<<",";
    }
    ~math(){delete []tab;delete []result;} //if i remove this program exit normally
};

math::math(int n){
    cout<<"Write elements: ";
    tab=new float[n];
    result=new float[50];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>*(tab+i);
}

void math::subtract(math y,int x){ //if i dont call this the program exit normally with destructor
    size=x;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        result[i]=tab[i]-y.tab[i];
}


    void main(void){


int n1,n2;
    cout<<"Write elements of sir1: ";
    cin>>n1;
    math sir1(n1);
    cout<<"Write elements of sir2: ";
    cin>>n2;
    math sir2(n2);
    sir1.subtract(sir2, n1<n2 ? n1:n2); //also if i comment this line the program exit normally with or without destructor
    sir1.afis();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

PS: Hm i debug my code and it seems like a destructor is calls twice for the same object. So is this destructor right before subtract function and two destructors at the end, in total 3 destructors instead of 2. I don't understand why. 
PS2: I fix my problem by using math & parameter in subtract instead of math but i don't undertand why this called the destructor. Now my program works normally with delete. But can someone give me an explanation?

Comment: Alternatively forbid copy construction and pass by reference.

Comment: And `n1<n2 ? n1:n2` should be done inside `subtract` with `size`s.

Comment: Why i need a copy construction if there are two different instances of the class?

Comment: @JackDaniels It's a "[Rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)" violation. When you call `subtract`, you have two `math`'s (`sir2` and `y`) that have the same value for `tab`, so they both `delete[]` it when their destructors run. *Boom!*